# Can the export files option be limited in Rstudio client (open source edition)

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I want to disable the export options in Rstudio open source edition server.
I read in http://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/r-sessions.html that this option is available in the pro version,

```
allow-file-downloads
```

...but I could not find documentation related with this topic for the open source edition.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, and after asking for help to the people at Rstudio, I get the answer to this and is **that the export option could not be limited in the open source edition of Rstudio server**. **This option works only with the pro version.**
You can check this in https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/222515687-Limit-files-export-in-Rstudio-server-open-source-edition

I will try to limit at the S.O. level. I will post any workaround if I succeed.